# Prevenir que troca de orientação atualize a Activity

Tags: android

Tenho um problema, uma Activity minha possui uma lista de objetos multi-selecionáveis, com o long clique posso selecionar vários desses objetos e clicar no botão de remover, quando clico para remover, aparece um progress dialog que é executado por uma AssyncTask.

O problema é que quando altero a orientação do smartphone (tanto faz se altera para portrait ou landscape) a view é atualizada, e isso faz com que a thread pare causando um erro, como faço para impedir este erro? Ou impedir que o assynctask pare sem precisar fixar uma orientação?

Erro:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
WindowManagerGlobal.java line 372 in WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked()
android.view    
WindowManagerGlobal.java line 372 in WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked()
android.view    
WindowManagerGlobal.java line 301 in WindowManagerGlobal.removeView()
android.view    
WindowManagerImpl.java line 84 in WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate()
android.app 
Dialog.java line 332 in Dialog.dismissDialog()
android.app 
Dialog.java line 123 in Dialog$1.run()
android.os  
Handler.java line 808 in Handler.handleCallback()
android.os  
Handler.java line 103 in Handler.dispatchMessage()
android.os  
Looper.java line 193 in Looper.loop()
android.app 
ActivityThread.java line 5292 in ActivityThread.main()
```

Comment: vc ja tentou utilizar essa declaracao no manifest.xml: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"

Comment: deu certo, mas segundo o Google, não se deve fazer isso, e meu layout fica estranho, principalmente o banner do admob que não é alterado já que a view não atualiza, ai ele fica pequeno

Comment: Já tentou utilizar um `AsyncTaskLoader`? Como eles você não vai ter problemas com mudança de orientação, já que o ciclo de vida dele é gerenciado pelo `ActivityManager`.

Comment: não dá para usar o async loader, pois alem de usar progress dialog com dismiss no final, quando este dismiss é executado, ocorrem alterações na UI, bom pelo menos eu não sei como fazer alterações dentro do asynctaskloader... Eu acho que não da

Comment: talvez alguma maneira de bloquear a rotação enquanto o assync é executado? isso é possivel?

Comment: deixa pra la, eu bloquiei a tela mesmo, não consegui encontrar uma solução no google... Mas seria bom alguém responder dando o exemplo dessa configChanges, ou de outra coisa para eu aceitar aqui

Comment: Sim, é possível bloquear a rotação da tela enquanto a `AsyncTask` é executada. Não sei se é tão ruim assim, dado que ela volte ao normal depois... Mas usando o `AsyncTaskLoader` você usaria o método `onLoadFinished` para atualizar a interface, e ai não importa se a orientação mudou, ele vai executar na proxima `Activity` (supondo que começou a atualização na que foi destruída).

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver este problema abra o arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, daí na declaração da sua activity adicione a seguinte linha:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Exemplo:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.activity.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```